# Getting WebDriverException error while using Edge browser in robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I am getting the below error while using Edge as browser in my script (Chrome is working fine)

WebDriverException: Message: 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687

I have already placed the webdrivers in the folders and updated the path in environment variable, already checked the version compatibility.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you did to "updated the path in environment variable"? Did you restart your session after the update?

Comment: Restarted the machine after updating the environment variables. As I mentioned, its working fine for Chrome but not for Edge.

Comment: Which version of Edge browser and Edge webdriver are you using? *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe* is the webdriver for Edge Legacy. If you're trying to automate Edge Chromium which is the latest Edge browser, you can't use *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe*. Besides, which version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Edge
Version 97.0.1072.69 (Official build) (64-bit) ----

and Webdriver downloaded from
Release 97
Version: 97.0.1072.69: x86 | x64 | Mac | Linux | ARM64    (x64)----

Double click the .exe file and it appears - Starting MSEdgeDriver 97.0.1072.69

Comment: Hello Yu Zhou, it didn't work, error details given in the below comment. Same set-up worked in my personal laptop but not working in official laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the selenium version, Edge started working when I upgraded the Selenium Version > 4.

Answer (score 0):

I test with the same version of Edge and Edge WebDriver and it works well with Robot Framework. You can refer to the following steps:

1. Make sure the latest version of [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) have been installed in your computer.
2. Install `Browser` library from PyPi with pip:

   ```
   pip install robotframework-browser
   ```
3. Initialize the `Browser` library:

   ```
   rfbrowser init
   ```
4. Install `SeleniumLibrary`:

   ```
   pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
   ```
5. Download the corresponding version of Edge WebDriver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).
6. Add the path of **msedgedriver.exe** to Environment Variables Path like below:

   [image]
7. **Edge.robot** sample code:

   ```
   *** Settings ***
   Library   SeleniumLibrary

   *** Test Cases ***
   Example Test
       Open Browser  https://www.google.com  edge
   ```
8. Navigate to the path of **Edge.robot** in cmd and run it to automate Edge:

   ```
   robot Edge.robot
   ```

Comment: Hello, I couldn't install using "pip install robotframework-browser", it says "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/robotframework-browser/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/robotframework-browser/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping"

Comment: You can update the PIP and test again. If it still doesn't work, I think it might be related with your office network. Please connect to another network and test again. [Here's](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3883#issuecomment-380502861) also a similar issue you can refer to.